# Why is django form removing fields from a model?

Tags: python, django, forms

I got a tracking model, and an evidence model wit ha foreign to it. Im trying to upload a file in evidence related to that tracking...but when i try to save i got this error:

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/change_actions/tracking/create/1/
Django Version:     1.10.1
Exception Type:     RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    

Evidence has no tracking.
```

My view saves tracking form and then passes the id of that record to the evidence form as foreign.....but that error is like the form was eliminating the tracking field !!....these are my files :

**Models.py**

```
class Tracking(ModelBase):    
    activity = models.ForeignKey(
        Activity,
        verbose_name = 'Actividad', null = False)
    code = models.CharField('Codigo de seguimiento', max_length=50)
    observation = models.TextField('Avance a la fecha', max_length=2000)
    tracking_date = models.DateTimeField('Fecha de seguimiento')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.observation

class Evidence(ModelBase):

    tracking = models.ForeignKey(
        Tracking,
        related_name = 'Tracking_evidence',
        verbose_name = 'Seguimiento', null = False)
    evidence = models.FileField(verbose_name = 'Evidencia', null = True, upload_to='documents/')
```

**This is the form.py:**

```
class EvidenceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tracking = kwargs.pop('tracking')
        super(EvidenceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super(EvidenceForm, self).clean()
        self.instance.tracking.id = self.tracking

    class Meta:
        model = Evidence
        fields = ['tracking', 'evidence']
```

**And the view to it :**

```
class TrackingCreateView(View):

    template_name = ['change_actions/tracking_create.html']
    breadcrumb = [{'name': 'Registro de seguimiento', 'url': None}]

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = TrackingForm()
        form_evidence = EvidenceForm(tracking = None)
        activity = Activity.objects.get(pk = kwargs['activity_id'])
        return render(request, self.template_name,{
            'form_tracking': form,'breadcrumb': self.breadcrumb,
            'activity': activity,'form_evidence': form_evidence})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = TrackingForm(request.POST)
        activity = Activity.objects.get(pk = request.POST['activity_id'])
        self.breadcrumb[0]['url'] = reverse(
            'change_actions:tracking_create',
            kwargs = {'activity_id': activity.id })
        context = {
            'breadcrumb': self.breadcrumb, 'activity': activity,
            'form_tracking': form}

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form_evidence = EvidenceForm(
                request.POST, request.FILES, tracking = form.instance.id)

            if form_evidence.is_valid():
                form_evidence.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Seguimiento registrado correctamente')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(
                    'change_actions:activity_detail',
                    kwargs = {'activity_id': activity.id }))
            else:
                context.update({'form_evidence': form_evidence}) 
                return render(request, self.template_name, context)
        else:
            context['form_tracking'] = form
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Any idea why I am getting this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are setting `tracking` manually, then you should leave it out of your form's fields. Having your models inherit from `ModelBase` instead of `models.Model` is extremely unusual.

Comment: We need more information. Could you add your POST data while creating the object? And the full stack trace. Try debug after `form.save()`.